# AJAX call during server request is failing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using a button to trigger an AJAX call to retrieve data from an SQL database. The problem I'm having is when the button click also triggers a call to the server, the AJAX call fails.

Code:

```
$('.ptimage').click(function () {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
    if (dataStore.getItem('mlist') == null || dataStore.getItem('flist') == null) {
        alert('isnull');
        var nulldata = {};
        nulldata.nullvar = "thing";

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            nulldata: nulldata
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/Getmf",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnErrorCall
         });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var arraystring = response.d;
            alert(arraystring);
            mlist = arraystring.split(',');
            mlist.splice(0, 1);
            mlist.splice(-1, 1);
            dataStore.setItem('mlist', JSON.stringify(mlist));
            flist = arraystring.split(';');
            flist.splice(0, 1);
            flist.splice(-1, 1);
            dataStore.setItem('flist', JSON.stringify(flist));
         }

         function OnErrorCall(response) {
             alert("fail");
         }
     }
     ptsession = dataStore.getItem('ptsessionval');
     if (ptsession !== focusedcell) {
        btn57.click();
    }
 })
```

So if ptsession != focusedcell, essentially if the clicked record is different from the current one, it will trigger a server call to the c# codebehind to get the new record.

If the record is different, the AJAX call fails and the call to the server from button57 (postback) succeeds. If the record is the same (so no call to the server from button57) the AJAX call succeeds. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I'm confused ... `(so no server call) the AJAX call succeeds` if there's no server call, there's no AJAX, so how can AJAX succeed if there is no server call?

Comment: It's another server call. So the button click is triggering a postback. It seems to be when I'm making 2 calls to the server at once the AJAX is failing

Comment: well, if you don't wait for the first AJAX call to complete before making the second AJAX call, that could be a problem if the second AJAX call needs to wait for the first AJAX call to complete - as your code has only one AJAX statement, it's a bit hard to see if this is the case

Comment: Is there a way for me to determine if that's what is happening? I really need these two calls to happen on that event. And if one does need to complete before the other is there a way I can do that in javascript?

Comment: Unless I'm blind, I see only one "server call", the `$.ajax` - as I have no clue where this *other* "server call" takes place, any suggestions I make would be a guess at best and probably lead you astray

Comment: Sorry I might be using the wrong terminology. Button57 triggers an event in the codebehind, and in that function there are about 9 SQL select commands to fill multiple gridviews. Would that be called a "server call"? I honestly don't know. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: A button in Web Forms usually triggers a postback and thus a complete reloading of the page.

Comment: What effect does that have on the AJAX call?

Comment: @anesthetic Well if the page goes away then the JavaScript stops executing...